# currentTimeMillis with higher precision in java

Tags: android

I have an algorithm(AES) written in Java for an Android application which takes key for encryption, which is current time in milliseconds converted to string.
Now this algorithm needs higher precision than that provided by Java's

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Since decryption on server side is done in C# and it has higher precision.
I need to get the same key on Java side for encryption.

Example:
Java result: 1529909054937
Required result:1529909054.93721

Comment: Use System.nanoTime()

Comment: @AslamHossin That will not help. According to the documentation: "The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin." It's purpose is a high precision measurement of elapses times and should not be used as absolute time. see: [nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Comment: If you multiply the required result by 1000 and treat it as Integer the Numbers are identical. Just because I'm curios: What's the purpose of relying on such a high precision timestamp on Server and Client side. Usually you can't guarantee to have the client and the server clocks to run that highly synchronous, or what's the trick?

Comment: if you need float instead of integer for random seed, just generate fractional part somehow, i. e. taking last digits from System.nanoTime() or .currentTimeMillis() or anything

Comment: Actually i recently studied that server side checks if the request received is from a particular time window example 30 millis window but the decryption key calculated which is the value on client side for encryption is sent in the header. So for now i have put a decimal on the 1000th place and  appended "00" to the System.currentTimeMillis(). which works.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1529909054937 is millisecond
Number 1529909054.93721 is second 
. You can convert millisecond to second (i think type Long not double)